# mongoengine using Authentication Database

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I am not sure how to connect to a mongodb database that uses an authentication database with mongoengine.

On the command prompt I need to do `mongo hostname:27017/myApp -u "test" -p "test" --authenticationDatabase admin`, but I don't see where I'd pass this as an argument to mongoengine so I use the admin database for auth but connect to the myApp database for my models?

I believe this is where it's explained in the PyMongo guide:

https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/authentication.html

```
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> client = MongoClient('example.com')
>>> db = client.the_database
>>> db.authenticate('user', 'password', source='source_database')
```

and I found the pull request that added this to mongoengine:

https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/pull/590/files

It looks like you just add `authentication_source` as an argument to `connect` like `connect(authentication_source='admin')`.  It'd be nice if it was better documented.

http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html?highlight=authentication_source

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [mongoengine connecting guide](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/connecting.html#guide-connecting), the `connect()` method support URI style connections. i.e.

```
connect(
   'project1'
   host='mongodb://username:password@host1:port1/databaseName'
)
```

In that sense, you can also specify the authentication source database as below:

```
"mongodb://username:password@host1:port1/database?authSource=source_database"
```

See also [MongoDB connection string URI](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connection-string-uri-format) for more MongoDB URI examples.
Also [Authentication options through connection string](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#authentication-options)

Comment: this isn't what I'm asking, the authentication source needs to be explicitly stated and so what you sent won't work

Comment: @Rob updated.  I've extracted the information out of the link which let's you specify authentication source via the URI.

Answer (score 5):

The API has been updated, so this is the right way to do it now:

```
connect('mydb',
        host="localhost",
        username="admin",
        password="secret",
        authentication_source='your_auth_db')
```

Comment: I believe the API has been updated since I asked this question back in 2016, could you indicate that in your answer?

Answer (score 2):

The solution suggested doesn't work for me. What does work:
just add a authSource argument to the connect method as you would do with pymongo MongoClient method. Example:

```
connect('database_name', host='host', username="username", 
password="password",authSource='authentication_database_name')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy solution that worked for me.

```
connect(db="database_name", host="localhost", port=27017, username="username", 
password="password", authentication_source="admin")
```